# CSS - How to make a square/squares fit and resize inside a div when added more squares?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a loyalty card in html and css, and i have an option that the user can select the number of squares that are inside the div.

My problem is when the user select more that a specific number,the squares get out of the div instead of resize and fit the div.

Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the code:

```css
#card{
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 400px
}

#squares{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
  top: 10px;
}

.square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #1e2023;
  margin: 5px;
 display: inline-block
}

#cardDescription{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

#userPhoto{
 position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
 <div id="card">
      <img id="userPhoto"/>
      <div id="squares">
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="cardDescription">
        <h1>Test text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If anyone can help me i would appreciated

Comment: it's not out of the div but the text is on the top of them

Answer (score 0):

You used so many position absolute. Position absolute doesn't have height so you shoul give it the value so can't get main result.
Use your  image as background.
And only use position absolute for your text.
I made changes to our code.

```css
    #card{
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  background: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/64/200/300.jpg?hmac=9MtSCC-H4DQRFtYARRhBDmbZhrJlRQJ2NQLowTY7A-s') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#squares{
 width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #1e2023;
  margin: 5px;
 display: inline-block
}

#cardDescription{
position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

#userPhoto{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
 <div id="card">
      <div id="squares">
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
        <span class="square"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="cardDescription">
        <h1>Test text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could completely avoid the usage of positions by using CSS Flexbox. This way, the elements will automatically wrap up following the same structure.

Also, you could get the container to grow and not overflowing by setting min-height instead of height.

If you would like a more comprehensive guide to CSS Flexbox, you could check out [CSS Tricks' Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#card {
  min-height: 250px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
}

#userPhoto {
  margin: 15px;
}

#squares {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #1e2023;
}

#cardDescription {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <img id="userPhoto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  <div id="squares">
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
    <span class="square"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="cardDescription">
    <h1>Test text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```